# SVG error when using pathAnimator javascript

Tags: javascript, svg, pathanimator

I am trying to use the basic demo of a javascript called "pathAnimator", [which can be found here](https://github.com/yairEO/pathAnimator).

The example code uses a very simple SVG string for demo purposes. But even this basic example generates an SVG error:

```
Argument 1 of SVGPathElement.getPointAtLength is not a finite floating-point value.
```

The demo code is as follows:

```
var path = "M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z"; // an SVG path
    pathAnimator = new PathAnimator( path ),    
    speed = 6,              
    reverse = false,        
    startOffset = 0,        
    easing = function(t){ t*(2-t) };

pathAnimator.start( speed, step, reverse, startOffset, finish, easing);

function step( point, angle ){
    // do something every "frame" with: point.x, point.y & angle
}

function finish(){
    // do something when animation is done
}
```

Is this an error in the SVG string or is this just faulty code?

Answer (score 0):

The `easing` function does not return a value. Try:

```
easing = function(t){ return t*(2-t); };
```